# In ui-grid how can i bind my click function on the original nextPage button

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

[image]

How can I bind my click function on the nextpage button in angular-ui-grid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify their template and add your own ng-click function. I created a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/RweUcYP9Chpg9lDvc2en?p=preview).

Template

```
$templateCache.put('ui-grid/pagination', ...
```

Add your ng-click to the template

```
ng-click=\"pageNextPageClick(); grid.appScope.myFunc();\"
```

Provide that function in their `scopeProvider`

```
appScopeProvider: {
  myFunc: function() {
    console.log('clicked');
  },
},
```

Comment: I think it's not good to change the original TemplateCache. if i change it, the next time i use it ,how to add myFuncTwo to the click function and remove myFuncOne. Is there any function makes it possibile for me to watch the click event on the nextPage button in my controller.

Comment: thanks a lot, when i read your plunkr i konw what you mean. Your answer is exactly what i need